# previewing the SQL Statements before migration using Flyway

Tags: flyway

I am new to Flyway and I am  using Flyway 2.1 code base for migration and execution of SQL statements on a previous schema version using Flyway. Once i execute my newer SQL statements the version entry in the metadata table is incremented.

But before I migrate my new version of the schema (i.e before I migrate/ execute the newer SQL statements on the database schema), I would like to capture all the new SQLs in another preview.sql file, so that the DBAs can see the SQLs before they proceed with the migrate.

I plan to do this by adding a flyway.preview() method to the Flyway.java file. Could you please let me know what other files would need to be changed to accomplish this?

Also, I only want to do this if the new version is > current schema version currently in the database. I checked the 2.1 code but the  SchemaVersion class has been deprecated in 2.1 and I am not sure how to obtain the current version from the database.

I would appreciate your help or any suggestions that would correct my approach.

Thank you

Comment: There's possible overlap between what you're doing and this: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/87 - Maybe once you've built your solution you can submit it via a pull request?

Answer (score 2):

The necessary abstractions are not in place yet to support this, but I plan on adding them over the next few weeks to support batch updates in 2.2. Once that is done, it should be much easier to implement this.

As for querying the state of the DB, you have the Flyway.info() to assist you.

Comment: Hi Axel, Thank you for your response. Per your response to my post, would there be a preview command along the lines of info ? Meaning, if I do a flyway.cmd preview, would that output the list of SQLs that are going to be applied? As I am currently trying to implement that functionality , I am curious to know. Thank you

Comment: No, I would implement it in such a way that you can switch executors. Either execute to jdbc or to stdout or something like that.

Comment: Hi Alex, I would like to print the same ascii table that is being printed on the console to a text file in the same format..is there anyway the table can be exported? Thanks

Comment: It is part of the private API (can change anytime, use at your own risk). Have a look at the sources of the command-line tool.

Comment: How did this go? I'm currently looking at bringing in Flyway and the ability to preview / export migrations (for use in environments where we won't be able to use flyway straight away) would be quite useful.